# How to wait for the user action on http retry in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement retry functionality for http calls in angular based on user action. If rest api returns error, confirmation popup will be shown to the user. If user clicks ok, need to retry the http call. I am able to retry using "retryWhen". But how to wait for the user action?. PFB my sample code
Is there any other way in angular other than retryWhen?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      retryWhen(error => 
        error.pipe(
          concatMap((err, count) => {
            this.confirmPopop();
            this.retrySubject.subscribe(data=>{
              return of(err);
              //how to wait for here
            })
            
          }),
          delay(10000)
        )
      )
}
```

Comment: If you are creating a dialog anyway, just send the request when the user clicks the button instead of making it part of the rxjs pipe.

Comment: I am planning to write this logic globally. So I will not know which endpoint I have to call

Comment: refer to this page . here all the failed calls will be called again after token refresh https://gist.github.com/Gribanov/c6cce5a563ca0ba55591f15a96312db5

Comment: You can grab the url from the failed request right there and pass it in as an argument in your `confirmPopup()`

Comment: I tried. But i want to return the response to actual caller. If I make retry call from popup, how to return the response to the actual caller?

Comment: use `delayWhen` ? like this `error.pipe(delayWhen(() => this.retrySubject))`